# Box with rounded corners and a colored border

Tags: cs6

None of the answers worked for me.  My question is simple.  In CS6 I want to create a rectangle box with rounded corners and a border. Can anyone answer it in a simple way that WORKS?

Comment: Greetings! It would be of great help to us all if you edited your question to include some images of what you hope to achieve and what you have tried. Saves everyone time, and increases the chances that you will get a good answer.

Comment: Hi Dan, "CS6" isn't of much help. That describes a suite of programs which includes Photoshop, Illustrator, InDesign, Dreamweaver, etc. If you can specify what program you want to work in, we might be able to help you. Also, you say "none of the answers worked." What answers did you find? Did you look on the Adobe forums or the help site?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only saying cs6, I am describing this in Illustrator, as that makes the most sense, considering the information you give.

Make a box.
Go `effect` - `stylize` - `rounded corners`
Choose the radius of your rounded corners.

[image]

Choose a brush from the brush palette, or make one yourself:

[image]

If you only want a plain border, choose a thickness and plain:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are the instructions for Photoshop:

Select the Round Rectangle Tool

[image]

Set your radius for the corner curve. I've set mine to 12px

[image]

Draw your rounded corner box. I've renamed my shaper layer.

[image]

Now open the 'Styles' palette. I've got loads in mine. Select one, making sure your layer with the shape on is still highlighted.

[image]

Now on the Layer palette, your rounded corner shape with have style properties. You can click on these and edit to get the right visual design. I've unchecked the Styles I applied early and enabled two new ones — the Color Overlay and most importantly the Stroke property which gives me a border.

I would save this as a 'New Style' which I could apply to other rounded boxes.

[image]

Finished result

[image]